# Two network interfaces use for up and down

Tags: networking, network-bridge

I've setup Ubuntu Server 14.04 as a virtual machine using vSphere. When I created the machine I set it up with 2 network cards.

Is it possible to set one as a download interface and another as upload? We'll be using this server as a build system, which takes a lot of data from flat CSV files, then turns them into a MySQL table. We run our software from this same MySQL database too, so we'd want good network performance.

Comment: Are the 2 vitual NIC's hooked up on the same virtual switch within vSphere ? In other word, are they using the same physical adapter(s) of your host ? In this case, no reason to create two virtual NIC's as the network traffic ends up finally on the same physical adapters.

Comment: Yeah, they're both virtual, but they point to different physical cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not posible to use one interface for download only and one for upload only.

Comment: Ok, can I bridge them to share the bandwidth?

Comment: I don't think that would have a great effect without some sort of Load Balancing.

Comment: Yes, you can bridge multiple network interface together using various scenario (adding all bandwith together, one as backup of the other, ...). In Linux world, this is called *bonding*. Explanation can be found here : [link](http://backdrift.org/howtonetworkbonding)